# Find limit of trigonometric function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{\tan^3(3x)-\sin^3(3x)}{x^5}$$
I think it should be decomposed with $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$ but I'm always getting indefinity $\frac{0}{0}$.

Comment: What is $tg(x)$?

Comment: Use L'Hopitals rule

Comment: We could use L'Hopitals rule, like the users above mentioned, but how do you define $tg(x)$?

Comment: or is it maybe $tg(3x)^3$?

Comment: it is $$(\tan(3x))^3$$ that is clear

Comment: @123 but you are not the same as who asked the question?

Comment: @mathreadler No I am not but I have seen $tg$ written for $\tan x$

Comment: i think at $$a^3-b^3$$, but if this would help?

Comment: $$\tan^3 3x-\sin^3 3x=\frac{729}2 x^5 + \frac{10935}8 x^7 + \frac{150903}{16} x^9+\ldots$$

Comment: this helps, $$\frac{729}{2}$$

Comment: @paulinho - I've see older text use tg for $\tan$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\begin{align}&\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\tan^3 3x - \sin^3 3x}{x^5} &\\= &\lim_{x \to 0} (\sin^3 3x)\dfrac{1 - \cos^3 3x}{x^5}&\\=\,  &27 \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{(1 - \cos 3x)}{x^2}(1 + \cos 3x + \cos^2 3x) &\\=\, &81 \lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{(1 - \cos 3x)}{x^2}\end{align}$$

Let $x = 2y$

$$\lim_{y \to 0} \dfrac{(1 - \cos 6y)}{(2y)^2} = \lim_{y \to 0} \dfrac{(2\sin^2 3y)}{(2y)^2} = \lim_{y \to 0} \dfrac{(\sin^2 3y)}{2(y)^2} = \dfrac92$$

So, $$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\tan^3 3x - \sin^3 3x}{x^5} = \dfrac{729}2$$.

Comment: Simple and all steps self explanatory +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Take $3x=a \to x=\frac{a}{3}$ 
$$\quad{\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{tg^3(3x)-\sin^3(3x)}{x^5}=\\
\lim_{a\rightarrow0} \frac{tg^3(a)-\sin^3(a)}{(\frac a3)^5}=\\3^5\lim_{a\rightarrow0} \frac{tg^3(a)-\sin^3(a)}{(a)^5}=\\
3^5\lim_{a\rightarrow0} \frac{(\tan(a)-\sin(a))(\tan^2(a)+\sin^2(a)+\tan (a).\sin (a))}{(a)^5}=\\
3^5\lim_{a\rightarrow0} \frac{(\tan(a)-\sin(a))}{(a)^3}.\frac{(\tan^2(a)+\sin^2(a)+\tan (a).\sin (a))}{(a)^2}=\\
3^5\lim_{a\rightarrow0} \frac{(\tan(a)-\sin(a))}{(a)^3}.\lim_{a\rightarrow0}\frac{(\tan^2(a)+\sin^2(a)+\tan (a).\sin (a))}{(a)^2}=\\
3^5\lim_{a\rightarrow0} \frac{(\tan(a)-\sin(a))}{(a)^3}.\lim_{a\rightarrow0}\underbrace{\frac{\tan^2(a)+\sin^2(a)+\tan (a).\sin (a)}{(a)^2}}_{3}=\\
3^6\lim_{a\rightarrow0} \frac{(\tan(a)-\sin(a))}{(a)^3}=\\
3^6\lim_{a\rightarrow0} \frac{(\frac{\sin 
(a)}{\cos (a)}-\sin(a))}{(a)^3}=\\
3^6\lim_{a\rightarrow0} \frac{(\frac{\sin 
(a)-\sin(a)\cos (a)}{\cos (a)})}{(a)^3}=\\
3^6\lim_{a\rightarrow0} \frac{(\frac{\sin 
(a)-\sin(a)\cos (a)}{1})}{\cos (a).(a)^3}=\\
3^6\lim_{a\rightarrow0} \frac{\sin 
(a)-\sin(a)\cos (a)}{(a)^3}=\\
3^6\lim_{a\rightarrow0} \frac{\sin 
(a)(1-\cos (a))}{\cos (a).(a)^3}=\\
3^6\lim_{a\rightarrow0} \underbrace{\frac{\sin 
(a)}{\cos (a).(a)}}_{1}.\lim_{a\rightarrow0}\frac{(1-\cos (a))}{(a)^2}=\\
3^6\lim_{a\rightarrow0}\frac{(1-\cos (a))}{(a)^2}=\\
3^6\underbrace{\lim_{a\rightarrow0}\frac{2\sin^2(\frac a2)}{(a)^2}}_{\frac 12}=\\\frac {3^6}{2}}$$